# NEED HELP FAST connecting three-wire wiper motor to an AA battery holder

Tags: motor, switches, dc-motor

I'm new here and I had a problem that needs urgent attention.

I have a three wired wiper motor that I want to get moving. I want to use my AA battery holder but the wires didn't work when I connected them.

Can I get instructions as to how to connect the motor to the battery and how to get the motor moving when I press the switch?

Materials:

- Wiper motor compatible with Jeep CJ5 76-83 front new W/ 3-wire plug (red, black, and green)
- AA battery holder with batteries (red and black wires.)
- Limit switch with common, normally open, and normally closed settings on the bottom.

[image]

Comment: You need a 12V power source which can supply enough current for such a motor. Those wimpy AA's aren't even close to what such a motor requires.

Comment: Oh ok. I have multiple AA holders though so can I join them together?

Comment: That motor will **not** work with that battery.  It is made to run on 12 volts and it will draw several amperes of current.  Your AA cells can deliver 4.5 volts (but no where near enough current) if you put them in series.  They might deliver the current if used in parallel, but then you only have 1.5V - and again it won't work.

Comment: No, you'd be able to get to 12V that way but it still won't be even close to the required current. Think more in the direction of a small lead acid battery.

Comment: @Unimportant you actually can get several amps out of AA's though those wimpy holders may be an issue at such currents.  AA NiCd's have quite impressive power density... a co-worker had a motor glider he referred to as the "flying welder".  But yes, for longetivity a large *capacity* battery would be good.

Comment: By the way, welcome to this free question and answer community site. It's a pleasure to inform you that your urgency has no positive effect on our willingness and ability to help you.

Comment: `NEED HELP FAST` ... find someone with knowledge of basic electric circuits

Comment: Yeah, I see your points. I appreciate the responses (sorry for the urgency title though). I tried them in series and parallel and they didn't work. I'm thinking of using a 12-volt lipo battery instead. Do you think that should suffice? Or would I need something bigger?

Answer (score 2):

An automotive wiper motor will require 12 volts - your two AA cells only provide 3 volts - probably not enough to move the motor.

Also, the motor probably requires around 3 Amps - far too much for AA cells, even if you had enough AA cells in series to make 12 volts.

Eight C or D cells in series would probably work, but a 12 volt lead-acid or gell-cell battery would be better.

*** Edit to add wiring info ***

Wire colours are a guess - automotive wiring colours are strange...

Black - Ground

Red - switched +12V Wiper On

Green - always on +12V to Park limit switch - provides power to move the wiper to the park position when the Red +12 is switched off.

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself to the store "FAST" because you're going to need somewhere between 8 and 10 AA's (depending on type) in series to make what appears to be a 12 volt or so automotive motor work.

The two you picture would give you only around 3 volts, which is nowhere near enough to overcome even the mechanical drag of the motor and gearbox alone, nevermind doing any useful work at the output shaft.

Given the likely current requirements you might be better off getting C or D cells if you want this to work for any period of time.  Or maybe a 12 volt gel cell.

Then there's the question of what the three wires do; easiest way to find out would be to find a 3rd party service manual for the vehicle, or probe the voltages when its in operation on the vehicle.  You could try experiments with a current limited bench supply.  One likely possibility is the one wire is permanently connected to the supply, and one of the others is connected for the desired direction; that would especially fit with the possibility that there could be limit switches inside which would lock out rotation in one direction but not the other.  Dissasembling the gearbox might yield more clues, and some cost of having some spring fly across the room never to be seen...

Comment: One wire will be Ground, one is +12 to the motor, the third wire is always-on +12 through a limit switch to the motor, to drive the motor to the park position when main power is removed.

Comment: Interesting design and explanation. I have to admit that while I read "wiper" I was somehow incorrectly thinking "window"